# Unable to use <where> linq command in Azure API call

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to build a UWP app with an Azure database + Azure Mobile Service. Though when I try to get my data, with a linq `where` clause, I get an unclear error exception. `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` -> `{"The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)"}`

Can I not use where in my Azure call? Is there some way I can get around this?

Code I use:

```
    public static ObservableCollection<ReisItem> Reizen { get; set; }
    public async Task getReizen()
    {
        string currentlyLoggedInUser = App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId;
        Reizen = await App.MobileService.GetTable<ReisItem>()
                       .Where(c => c.userID == currentlyLoggedInUser).ToCollectionAsync();
    }
```

PS: I know I should technically use .equals in the method above, but Azure said it doesn't support that or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting for the request before doing anything with it.

```
public static ObservableCollection<ReisItem> Reizen { get; set; }
public async Task getReizen()
{
    string currentlyLoggedInUser = App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId;
    var result = await App.MobileService.GetTable<ReisItem>();
    Reizen = new ObservableCollection<ReisItem>(result.Where(c => c.userID == currentlyLoggedInUser));
}
```

Comment: I think you might be on to something, but when I try your suggestion I get syntax errors. First of all I added .ToCollectionAsync() to the second line, where you declare result. I get an error at the third line, which says IENumerable does not contain a definition for .ToCollectionAsync() and no extension method could be found.     When I try to remove that second .ToCollectionAsync(), it says it cannot convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection. I've considered using a for loop to get around this, but I dunno how to make the loop wait for the result.

Comment: I made an edit, I think that should solve what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thanks a lot! In hindsight, I should have known that, but live & learn I guess. For the record, in the last line there should be an additional <ReisItem> after ObservableCollection. In case anyone else stumbles upon this question later. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Sometimes just takes another pair of eyes. Added the generic argument to the answer, I assume that what you meant?

Comment: Correct. The last line would be `Reizen = new ObservableCollection<ReisItem>(result.Where(c => c.userID == currentlyLoggedInUser));`  If you wanna be completly correct in regards to syntax. So that looks good, yes.